# GPU Driver Support How Many GPUs?

Tags: gpu-mining, cryptonote, mining-hardware, mining-software, mining-setup

Looking to build about 50 mining rigs... I can't figure out how to determine which GPUs support how many... For example... If I want to put 11 AMD Radeon RX 480s on one board, will the stock driver support it? What should I look for when buying GPUs? I have the new ASUS boards that hold 19... They only hold 9-11 AMDs with driver support... Any help is appreciated...

I am mining Monero also... Any advice on how to choose GPUs is appreciated... Due to shortages, I'm just snagging up older hardware... Money isn't a problem... If you have any advice on filling these boards, let me knows please... Thanks